# Dojo / Dijit Layouts without Non-Semantic HTML

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, dojo, dijit.layout

I'm new to dojo/dijit, coming from a Backbone/Marionette background.

Right now I'm working with dijit's layout system, but I'm kinda shocked by the amount of non-semantic html in the examples needed to get it moving. For example, an accordion (from http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html):

```
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer" style="width: 200px; height: 95%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #1">accordion pane #1</div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #2">accordion pane #2</div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionPane" title="pane #3">accordion pane #3</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this without having to add all that into the HTML? Specifically, I'm trying to find the equivalent of 'regions' in dijit layout, so I can include a template for a layout and place views in and out of that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create content panes programmatically as in this [accordion container example](http://jsfiddle.net/stafamus/emr74/). (AccordionPane is deprecate, just use ContentPane instead)

```
var accordion = new AccordionContainer({
    style: "width: 200px; height: 100%;"
}).placeAt(document.body);

var content = new ContentPane({
        title: "content1",
        style:"height:100px"
    });
accordion.addChild(content);
accordion.startup();
```

if you need to use regions, bordercontainer's design property gives you that as in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/stafamus/ntSDM/). you can put an accordioncontainer in one of the content panes there...